# $H_n(S^n,A)$ is not trivial

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $(H_n)_{n\in \Bbb{Z}}, (\partial_n)_{n\in \Bbb{Z}}$ be an ordinary homology theory with values in the category of $R$-modules. Let $A\subset S^n$ be a proper subset. Then $H_n(S^n, A)$ is not trivial.

Somehow we must use the long exact sequence:

$$...\to H_n(A)\to H_n(S^n) \to H_n(S^n, A) \to H_{n-1}(A) \to H_{n-1}(S^n)\to ...$$

but I haven't been able to figure out how. Can you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x \in S^n$ not be in $A$. Then $A \subset S^n \setminus \{x\} \cong \Bbb R^n$, and this is contractible. The the map $H_n(A) \to H_n(S^n)$ factors through $H_n(A) \to H_n(\Bbb R^n) \to H_n(S^n)$, and must therefore be zero.

So the sequence $0 \to H_n(S^n) \to H_n(S^n,A)$ is exact, and $H_n(S^n,A)$ is nontrivial as desired.